# Django get_context_data never gets called in MyCustomTemplateView?

Tags: django, django-templates

**EDIT:** I've completely misunderstood the right way to subclass TemplateView, which is at the basis of this error. I over rid the get method as well - which I shouldn't have in a TemplateView.

*Original question:*

I have created a subclass of `TemplateView`:

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):

  def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyTemplateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['current_business_view'] = self.kwargs.get('user_business_id')
    return context
```

All my Views subclass MyTemplateView.

I was expecting that get_context_data was going to be called, but it looks like it never gets called - what am I missing here?

Comment: how does looks route for this view in urls.py?

Comment: I've completely misunderstood how to use the TemplateView, which is the basis of my error. It all works like it should, I over rid the wrong methods.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this issue, The `get_context_data` method is only called for the view class that handles the target url. That said, if you have this issue Sjaak was experiencing, also check your `urls.py` configuration and be sure the desired url isn't pointing to a different, unexpected, view (twas what happened to me and led me to this posting).

Answer (score 1):

I think the function is called but the value of user_business_id is None.

Try debugging with Python debugger.

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):

  def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
      context = super(MyTemplateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
      context['current_business_view'] = self.kwargs.get('user_business_id')
      import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
      return context
```

Now when you do python manage.py runserver the server will stop at the breakpoint.
You can type print context to see what's in the context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering, however I completely misunderstood the use of TemplateView - see my comment in the openingpost.